# Variable arguments with partial applied functions

Tags: scala, variadic-functions, partialfunction

I have a compilation problem on the following code.

```
object Main {
    def main(args:Array[String]) = {
      def collectBigger(median:Int)(values:Int*) = values.filter { _ > median }
      val passedRanks = collectBigger(5)_
      //this compiles
      println(passedRanks(Seq(5,9,5,2,1,3)))
      //this doesn't
      println(passedRanks(5,9,5,2,1,3))
    }
}
```

The sample is inspired from com.agical.gsl which is a scala adapter to swt. I assume it used scala features before scala 2.8.

The error is `too many arguments for method apply: (v1: Seq[Int])Seq[Int] in trait Function1` and is connected on how the variable arguments are passed to a partially applied function.

Thanks for any hints that you could give.

Comment: When you partially apply the function collectBigger it appears that the return function is of type `Seq[Int] => Seq[Int] = <function1>`. If you do however apply both arguments without partially applying it does work as you want.

Comment: I would also like to know why you are experiencing that kind of behaviour

Comment: but your code works fine in my ide. the scala version of mine is 2.11.7, what happened?

Comment: I get the same error in scala 2.11.8 and in scala 2.10.6 in both eclipse and sbt.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To put it simply, you can have a varargs *method* in scala, but not a varags *function*. Why? Well, all functions have a `FunctionN[T1..TN,R]` type. In your case, it is `Function1[Seq[Int], Seq[Int]]`.

There is simply no type for a "varargs function", so whenever you convert a method to a function, it must be desugared into the `Seq..` notation.

Answer (score 0):

You used to be able to:

```
$ scala210 -Yeta-expand-keeps-star
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.5 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_95).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> def f(vs: Int*) = vs.sum
f: (vs: Int*)Int

scala> f(1,2,3)
res0: Int = 6

scala> val g = f _
g: Int* => Int = <function1>

scala> g(1,2,3)
res1: Int = 6
```

But no longer.

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6816

Answer (score 0):

An workaround a value with apply as suggested by Rob Norris

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    {
      //workaround use Seq as requested
      def collectBigger(median: Int)(values: Int*) = values.filter { _ > median }
      val passedRanks = collectBigger(5)_
      println(passedRanks(Seq(5, 9, 5, 2, 1, 3)))
      println(passedRanks(5, 9, 5, 2, 1, 3))//compile error: too many arguments for method apply: (v1: Seq[Int])Seq[Int] in trait Function1
    }

    {
      //
      def collectBigger(median: Int) = new { def apply(values: Int*) = values.filter { _ > median } }
      val passedRanks = collectBigger(5)
      import scala.language.reflectiveCalls
      println(passedRanks(Seq(5, 9, 5, 2, 1, 3)))//compile error (as expected): type mismatch; found : Seq[Int] required: Int

      //this now works
      println(passedRanks(5, 9, 5, 2, 1, 3))
    }
  }
}
```